# Textblob giving memory error while using NaiveBayesAnalyzer on large dataset

Tags: python, textblob

I am opening each text file and assigning it a label -- pos or neg as per for training NaiveBayes classifier.The data set contains about 12,000 txt files. I am using TextBlob library for sentiment analysis

```
train = [('I dont like this movie','neg')]
path  = 'C://TextDemo//senti//aclImdb//train//neg//*.txt'
for f in glob.glob(path):
with open(f, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as read_file:
    for line in read_file:
        train.append(((line.replace("<br />","")),'pos'))

cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
```

Comment: You use up too much memory. So either buy more memory (and make sure you use 64 Bit Python), or train your classifier in batches.

Comment: Alright! Thank you. I thought I didn't optimize my code :) I will try this of 16GB RAM.